# Searching for keywords and open specific OneNote page

Tags: sharepoint-online

If I search for a keyword in SharePoint, it shows me the right OneNote document.
After clicking on the link, it will open the last visited page.
Is there any possibility to click on the link and run OneNote with the page which contains the searched keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint online and i cannot reproduce your issue.

Where do you do the search? Try to search in another site and compare whether the issue exists.

Try to open the site in another browser and compare the results.

Comment: Hello Lisa, we do have a Lokal directory which contains the OneNote files. Searching for a keyword in the "Global Seach" of SharePoint Online shows me the right section of the OneNote. It although displays the right keyword in the Preview. But if I click on the link it opens OneNote with the Page that was closed by the last use.

Comment: Using other browsers leads to the same result.